# INSERT mysql_num_rows as a variable

Tags: php, mysql, insert, mysql-num-rows

I am creating a CMS in in which when you ADD NEW PAGE, a display_order will automatically grab the next highest number according to the number of rows already present.  Here's what I currently have:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['updateContent'])){

    require ("connection.php");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM pages";
    $result = $conn->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error());

    $content = $_POST['content'];
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];

    $order = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if (empty($id)){
        /** ADD NEW SLIDE*/
        $sql = "INSERT INTO pages (title, content, display_order, visible) VALUES ('".$title."', '".$content.", '".$order.", 0)";
    }else{
        /** UPDATE SLIDE*/
        $sql = "UPDATE pages SET content = '".$content."', title = '".$title."' WHERE id = '".$id."'";
    }

    if ($result){
        header("Location: admin.php");
    }
}

?>
```

What this code is doing is taking the HTML form that I'm using in a page called edit.php and determining if it is new page or simply a page that is being updated.  The error that I am getting is that NOTHING is posting to the database at all. If I remove the `$sql`, `$result` and `$order` lines.. the script works fine, but the display_order variable will not be set to the next highest number.

Comment: // comment the header line. Then post what you see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your query:

```
INSERT INTO pages (title, content, display_order, visible)
VALUES ('".$title."', '".$content.", '".$order.", 0)";
                                     ^-- here
```

Should be:

```
INSERT INTO pages (title, content, display_order, visible)
VALUES ('".$title."', '".$content."', ".$order.", 0)";
                                   ^-- quote goes here
```

Also, using `mysqli` doesn't magically protect you from SQL-insertion. Escape dat input!

Answer (score 0):

The common way to solve the situation is to use AUTO_INCREMENT field in pages table.
Sequentially insert and then ask for LAST_INSERT_ID

php way: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

native mysql way: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id